# Is there a way to disable auto-capitalization?

Tags: interface

I was creating display dimensions (aspect ratio) presets in the render options, going along with corresponding names (HD, Full HD, QHD, etc). However Blender automatically capitalizes the first letter in the name and prohibits capitalization for all the following letters. Is there an option to disable this?